# Age in years at a specific date

Tags: java, php, datetime

For eligibility to events I need to know the age of a competitor at a specific date.

Now the thing is the date calculations are checked in two places, an online PHP app where the entries are registered, and an offline Java app that runs the events.

So I have 2 versions of the same code, the PHP one was written originally and the Java is a conversion of that. (So that I am using the same calculations in both places).

My Java skills are very rusty.

I am happy to take any improvements onboard, but it is essential that both calculations return the same result.

### PHP

```
public function ageAt($age_reference_date) {
    $ts_ref = strtotime($age_reference_date);       
    list($dob_year, $dob_month, $dob_day) = explode('-', $this->date_of_birth);

    $age = date('Y', $ts_ref) - $dob_year;      

    if (date('md', $ts_ref) < $dob_month.$dob_day) {
        $age--;
    } 

    return $age;
}
```

### Java

```
public int ageAt(Date ageReferenceDate) {
    Calendar calAgeReferenceDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calDateOfBirth = Calendar.getInstance();
    int refDateMonth;
    int dobDateMonth;
    int age;

    calAgeReferenceDate.setTime(ageReferenceDate);

    calDateOfBirth.setTime(this.dateOfBirth);
    age = calAgeReferenceDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) - calDateOfBirth.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    refDateMonth = Integer.parseInt(String.format("%02d", calAgeReferenceDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + String.format("%02d", calAgeReferenceDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
    dobDateMonth = Integer.parseInt(String.format("%02d", calDateOfBirth.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + String.format("%02d", calDateOfBirth.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));

    if (refDateMonth < dobDateMonth) {
        age--;
    }

    return age;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8 you can more accurately represent the dateOfBirth with a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).
If the `ageAt()` method also takes a `LocalDate` as argument, then the age is easily computed using [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html).

```
public int ageAt(LocalDate ageReferenceDate) {
    return Period.between(dateOfBirth, ageReferenceDate).getYears();
}
```

It is fairly easy, albeit a bit verbose, to convert a `Date` instance to a `LocalDate` :

```
LocalDate localDate = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

The catch is that you need to interpret it vs. a `ZoneId`. A `Date` can be mapped to different `LocalDate`s depending on what `ZoneId` (`TimeZone`'s successor) it is evaluated against. You should use the `ZoneId` that was used when the `Date` was recorded. That is probably `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, but if your code can run on systems accross time zones, you can have a problem.

This is also the reason why it is a better idea to represent date of birth as a `LocalDate`, since it does away with that ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

**Java 8:** You can do what bowmore suggested and use LocalDate. If you can't change the method definition, you can convert a java.util.date to a java.time.localdate object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate

**Java 1.4+**: I personally use and prefer to use [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/) objects for doing things time-related. Take a look at what's available there. Specifically if you want years, they have a Years class which allows you to compute years between two dates.